# DrawImage Height Parameter Not Working

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2012, drawimage

I am making a WinForms app using VS2012 c++/cli and using DrawImage to display HD images captured from a webcam.

The images are 1920 x 1080 bitmaps that I am trying to display on a Panel control.  The Panel is 240 x 135 (i.e., exactly 1/8 of the HD image).

I am calling DrawImage as follows:

```
    System::Drawing::Rectangle destRect = System::Drawing::Rectangle(0,0,Cam0Panel->Width,Cam0Panel->Height);
    g->DrawImage(b,destRect);
```

This should specify to draw the image at the relative 0,0 location on the panel and size the image to be 240 x 135.  However, the image will not display.

If I change the Height parameter to specify the Panel->Bottom (which is the absolute position in the app - ~630), the image does display and is correctly sized for width but is not correctly sized for height.

Any idea what I am doing wrong or how to correctly resize and display the image?

Here is a complete version of the code.

```
    void Cam0Panel_Paint( Object^ /*sender*/, System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs^ e )
    {
        System::Drawing::Bitmap^ b = ImageWinArray[CHANNEL_SELECT0];
        Graphics^ g = e->Graphics;

        g->InterpolationMode = System::Drawing::Drawing2D::InterpolationMode::Bilinear;
        g->CompositingMode = System::Drawing::Drawing2D::CompositingMode::SourceCopy;
        System::Drawing::Rectangle destRect = System::Drawing::Rectangle(0,0,Cam0Panel->Width,Cam0Panel->Bottom);

        g->DrawImage(b,destRect);
    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is happening instead? What height is it using instead of the "right one"?

Comment: When the height is specified as the panel height (i.e., 135) nothing is displayed at all.  When I specify the height as 636 (i.e., the absolute location in the window), the image is displayed but is not resized properly vertically.

Comment: Your code is correct. It should work. If you use instead of the `destRect` a `point` at (0, 0) what do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.  The array storing the bitmaps was initialized but the scope of the initialization was not persistent enough.  Thus, the references stored in the array were potentially garbage cleaned up.  For some odd reason, the only way this was revealed was the vertical parameter on the drawimage call.  Once I corrected the initialization, the drawimage call worked correctly.